# I'm having trouble starting a container that will run a Rails 7 application using ESBuild and Sass

Tags: ruby-on-rails, bash, docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

The PSQL and REDIS container's start fine and the Dockerfile/Docker Compose work right up until the bin/dev script runs in the Rails container.  It looks to me like the required Gem's aren't installed in the container.  I use a small script to try and streamline the process, which runs without issue until the bin/dev command used by docker compose after the container starts.

The logs from the container are

```
2023-07-11 21:49:01 Installing foreman...
2023-07-11 21:49:02 Fetching foreman-0.87.2.gem
2023-07-11 21:49:02 Successfully installed foreman-0.87.2
2023-07-11 21:49:02 1 gem installed
2023-07-11 21:49:03 03:49:03 web.1  | started with pid 18
2023-07-11 21:49:03 03:49:03 css.1  | unknown command: yarn build:css --watch
2023-07-11 21:49:03 03:49:03 web.1  | /usr/local/bundle/gems/bundler-2.4.12/lib/bundler/definition.rb:524:in `materialize': Could not find jsbundling-rails-1.1.2, cssbundling-rails-1.2.0, redis-4.8.1, sassc-rails-2.1.2, devise-4.9.2, sassc-2.4.0, tilt-2.2.0, bcrypt-3.1.19, orm_adapter-0.5.0, responders-3.1.0, warden-1.2.9, irb-1.7.2, ffi-1.15.5, public_suffix-5.0.3 in locally installed gems (Bundler::GemNotFound)
2023-07-11 21:49:03 03:49:03 web.1  |   from /usr/local/bundle/gems/bundler-2.4.12/lib/bundler/definition.rb:197:in `specs'
2023-07-11 21:49:03 03:49:03 web.1  |   from /usr/local/bundle/gems/bundler-2.4.12/lib/bundler/definition.rb:254:in `specs_for'
2023-07-11 21:49:03 03:49:03 web.1  |   from /usr/local/bundle/gems/bundler-2.4.12/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:18:in `setup'
2023-07-11 21:49:03 03:49:03 web.1  |   from /usr/local/bundle/gems/bundler-2.4.12/lib/bundler.rb:171:in `setup'
2023-07-11 21:49:03 03:49:03 web.1  |   from /usr/local/bundle/gems/bundler-2.4.12/lib/bundler/setup.rb:23:in `block in <top (required)>'
2023-07-11 21:49:03 03:49:03 web.1  |   from /usr/local/bundle/gems/bundler-2.4.12/lib/bundler/ui/shell.rb:159:in `with_level'
2023-07-11 21:49:03 03:49:03 web.1  |   from /usr/local/bundle/gems/bundler-2.4.12/lib/bundler/ui/shell.rb:111:in `silence'
2023-07-11 21:49:03 03:49:03 web.1  |   from /usr/local/bundle/gems/bundler-2.4.12/lib/bundler/setup.rb:23:in `<top (required)>'
2023-07-11 21:49:03 03:49:03 web.1  |   from <internal:/usr/local/lib/ruby/site_ruby/3.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb>:85:in `require'
2023-07-11 21:49:03 03:49:03 web.1  |   from <internal:/usr/local/lib/ruby/site_ruby/3.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb>:85:in `require'
2023-07-11 21:49:03 03:49:03 web.1  |   from /src/config/boot.rb:3:in `<top (required)>'
2023-07-11 21:49:03 03:49:03 web.1  |   from bin/rails:3:in `require_relative'
2023-07-11 21:49:03 03:49:03 web.1  |   from bin/rails:3:in `<main>'
2023-07-11 21:49:04 03:49:04 web.1  | exited with code 1
2023-07-11 21:49:04 03:49:04 system | sending SIGTERM to all processes
2023-07-11 21:49:09 03:49:09 system | sending SIGKILL to all processes
```

The Dockerfile is:

```
# syntax=docker/dockerfile:1

ARG RUBY_VERSION=3.2.2

FROM ruby:${RUBY_VERSION}-slim

# OS Level Dependencies
RUN --mount=type=cache,target=/var/cache/apt \
  --mount=type=cache,target=/var/lib/apt,sharing=locked \
  --mount=type=tmpfs,target=/var/log \
  rm -f /etc/apt/apt.conf.d/docker-clean; \
  echo 'Binary::apt::APT::Keep-Downloaded-Packages "true";' > /etc/apt/apt.conf.d/keep-cache; \
  apt-get update -qq \
  && apt-get install -yq --no-install-recommends \
    build-essential \
    gnupg2 \
    less \
    git \
    libpq-dev \
    postgresql-client \
    libvips \
    curl

ENV LANG=C.UTF-8 \
  BUNDLE_JOBS=4 \
  BUNDLE_RETRY=3
  
WORKDIR /usr/src/app

RUN echo "Copying Gemfile in Dockerfile" 
COPY Gemfile* .
RUN gem update --system && gem install bundler && bundle install

COPY . .

EXPOSE 3000

CMD ["rails", "s"]
```

Though I do question whether I need the CMD line here?

The docker-compose is:

```
services:
  web:
    build: .
    command: bin/dev
    working_dir: /src 
    volumes:
      - .:/src
    ports:
      - "3000:3000"
    env_file:
      - rails.env
    depends_on:
      db:
        condition: service_healthy
      redis:
        condition: service_started
    stdin_open: true
    tty: true

  db:
    image: postgres:15
    expose:
      - "5432"
    ports:
      - "5432:5432"
    env_file:
      - rails.env
    volumes:
      - pg_data:/var/lib/postgresql/data
    healthcheck:
      test: pg_isready -U postgres
      interval: 2s
      timeout: 5s
      retries: 30

  redis:
    image: redis
    ports:
      - "6379:6379"
    volumes:
      - redis_data:/data

volumes:
  pg_data:
  redis_data:
```

And finally the script that sets everything up is run by `create-rails-app appName targetDirectory` with the script as:

```
#!/bin/bash

# # create the rails directory
mkdir "$2"
cd "$2" || { echo "Directory not found."; exit; }

# Variables
RAILS_PATH=$(PWD)
APP_PATH="$RAILS_PATH/$1"
DOCKER_PATH="$HOME/Development/Learning/Docker/Rails"

# run the rails command
echo "Creating Rails app $1 in $APP_PATH"
rails new "$1" -j esbuild -c sass -d postgresql
REDIS_GEM="gem \"redis\", \"~> 4.0\""
SASSC_GEM="gem \"sassc-rails\"\n\n"
DEVISE_COMMENT="# Use devise for user id & authorization\n"
DEVISE_GEM="gem \"devise\", \"~> 4.9\", \">= 4.9.2\""

echo "Updating Gemfile"
cd "$1" || { echo "Directory not found."; exit; }
sed '37d;49d' Gemfile > temp
awk -v"REDIS=$REDIS_GEM" \
    'NR==37{print REDIS}1' temp > temp2
rm temp
awk -v"SASSC=$SASSC_GEM" \
    -v"COMMENT=$DEVISE_COMMENT" \
    -v"DEVISE=$DEVISE_GEM" \
    'NR==49{print SASSC COMMENT DEVISE}1' temp2 > Gemfile
rm temp2
bundle install

# copy the docker & environment files
echo "Copying docker environment files"
cp "$DOCKER_PATH"/docker-compose.yml "$APP_PATH"
cp "$DOCKER_PATH"/Dockerfile "$APP_PATH"
cp ../rails.env "$APP_PATH"

# edit the database config
echo "Editing the database configuration"
USERNAME="  username: <%= ENV.fetch(\"POSTGRES_USER\") %>\n"
PASSWORD="  password: <%= ENV.fetch(\"POSTGRES_PASSWORD\") %>\n"
HOST="  host: <%= ENV.fetch(\"POSTGRES_HOST\") %>\n"
PORT="  port: <%= ENV.fetch(\"POSTGRES_PORT\") %>\n"

echo "Writing databse.yml"
awk -v"USER=$USERNAME" \
    -v"PASSWORD=$PASSWORD" \
    -v"HOST=$HOST" \
    -v"PORT=$PORT" \
    'NR==23{print USER PASSWORD HOST PORT}1' config/database.yml > config.yml
rm config/database.yml
mv config.yml config/database.yml

# run the containers
echo "Running the containers"
docker compose up -d
```

After running the script I can run the Rails app on my local machine using bin/dev but would like to the ability to do this through containers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like yarn is not installed.  But I'll tell you how'd I'd approach what you've done:
`docker-compose run --rm -it web bash`

Then I'd fool around in that container and see what's what.  `rails s` should do about what it does when you try to launch.  But at least you can then try to run `yarn` and also see where the gems went?

Oh, maybe you're vendor caching the gems during the build - and then in the compose you are mounting and working in /src - which then ignores the ones installed in /usr/src/app?

Comment: The second part of your comment seems very plausible, I will have a look at it.